# Android : Several activities sharing common code

Tags: java, android

I have an Android application composed by several Activities.  Most of them need to check whether an active network is available or not:

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    ...
}
```

I would like to move that code to a helper class in order to avoid the need to write that code in every Activity, but calls to `getSystemService` are only allowed from an Activity.

The other alternative is to move that code to a parent activity use inheritance but:

1. Every activity already extends from android.app.Activity
2. Some of my activities already extend from a common my.package.BaseActivity (Activity <- BaseActivity <- XXXActivity)

so I don't like this idea very much.

What do you recommend in this case?  Is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you could still create a helper class and pass a reference of the activity to it.

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context c) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) c.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) c.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    ...
}
```

getSystemService is a public method, so it should work outside of the Activity scope.

You could pass it by calling it like this:

```
helperClassObj.isNetworkAvailable(YourActivity.this);
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: This is cool solution, but you better make that helper method static, instead of requiring to hold an instance to helper object.

Comment: Thank you, now it seems so obvious :$

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use composition? Define a class with your logic and then put that class or an instance of it into the classes that need the method.

Comment: Yes, thanks, it is more or less the solution proposed by @xil3 in the accepter answer, defining a helper class.

Comment: Yup, similar idea.  But I think putting the logic into an object that you store in the Activity rather than passing your Activity out to an external object is often cleaner.